# Equivalent of ereg() call

Tags: php, preg-match, ereg

My server is running on php 5.3 now and I need to replace this call to ereg:

```
if (ereg("/$", $pref) === FALSE) 
{
  $pref .= '/';
}
```

I have tried this, among other things without any success:

```
if (preg_match('~/$~', $pref) === FALSE)
```

This results in http://example.com/index.phpwww/browse
If it makes any difference, this is a CodeIgniter 1.6.1 app that I've inherited.

I tried this:

```
if (ereg("/$", $pref) === 0)
```

as @PeterM suggested and now going to http://example.com takes me to http://example.com/index.php/www/browse , but that gives me the message of "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters." Is that be a valid CodeIgniter URL? Maybe I messed something up elsewhere in the code?

I changed line 126 of codeigniter/application/config/config.php to be:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

and I still get the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare it against `0`, not `false`. `preg_match` returns number of matches. It returns `false` only on error.

Comment: I did that and now going to http://example.com takes me to http://example.com/index.php/www/browse , but that gives me the message of "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters." I will update my question.

Comment: It seems there is some other problem than match. Try var_dump it

Comment: Thank you, this answered my original question. I ended up upgrading CodeIgniter to fix the rest of my problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(substr($pref, -1) !== '/'){

}
```

OR:

```
if($pref[strlen($pref)-1] !== '/' ){
 //not found
}
```

Comment: exactly how is the end of a string supposed to contain a boolean false? OP wants to check for a `/` at the end of the line, not a false.